# Video stuck in recording when resume camera after turning off

Tags: camera, mediastream, recordrtc

When I turn on camera after turning off my video stuck in recording.I am using recordRTC library for recording. My video stuck at phase where I turn off camera.

I want that correct video recorded.When resume/pause camera, in all cases recording should be correct.